# HTTP GET request always returns 301

Tags: http

I'm trying to obtain the HTML dump of some RFC's from IETF website, via a simple GET request. However, it responds with status code 301. I'm making use of `netcat` to simulate the HTTP GET request with the following command :

```
$ printf 'GET /html/rfc3986 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: tools.ietf.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' | nc tools.ietf.org 80
```

The following reply is obtained as a result of the above command :

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 09 Sep 2020 15:36:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Location: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 323
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Pad: avoid browser bug

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at tools.ietf.org Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

However, if I try to send a `HTTP/1.0` based `HEAD` request to the `Location` value determined in the above reply, I get status 404 in reply. I made use of `HEAD` method just to check the status code of the reply.

Command :

```
printf 'HEAD https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' | nc tools.ietf.org 80
```

Reply:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 09 Sep 2020 16:32:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Vary: accept-language,accept-charset,Accept-Encoding
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Language: en
Expires: Wed, 09 Sep 2020 16:32:18 GMT
```

Is there a mistake in the way I'm making use of `GET` method to obtain the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a plain text request to port 80, so the URL you are trying is effectively `http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986`

The response is telling you to instead request `https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986`. That's not a different path on the same server, but a full URL.

The difference is that it begins `https` meaning you need to make a TLS-secured connection on port 443.

That's not going to be possible with a trivial use of netcat, so you're better off using an HTTP client like curl or wget

Comment: No wonder, directly using 443 port instead of 80 gave status 400 as reply and mentioned a reasoning similar to yours.

Comment: Is there an RFC, that tells how to design a HTTPS based header?

Comment: @Argon HTTPS is (simplified) TLS + HTTP. You're going to have a _very very very_ difficult time constructing a HTTPS request manually using tools like netcat. You *might* be able to do it in conjuction with openssl, but why not just use something like `curl`?

Comment: @Argon On the one hand, yes, TLS is a public standard, just look it up. On the other hand, trying to write an implementation of network encryption from scratch just to download some web pages would be like trying to build a skyscraper because your garden shed isn't big enough. It's not something you're going to just do in an afternoon out of curiosity.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Evert. I'm actually trying to send HTTP requests via C. Because I stumbled upon the status code 301 in reply via the C code, I rushed to `netcat` to simulate the request to see if I did something wrong in C. When I obtained exactly same results in `netcat` too, then I came to SO. But I will give a shot to `curl` too.

Comment: @Argon curl has C bindings too!